# replicate addCCI (quantmod's chartSeries) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantmod

In the quantmod package, chartSeries provides the option to "addCCI" which is based on a moving average. The CCI chart uses a very good idea but is based on a moving average whereas I prefer to use a single long term average which is why Im trying to replicate the chart in ggplot2 instead of in quantmod.
[the addCCI picture I want to replicate is the bottom chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp8Ci.jpg)

I want to use the same concept of using a highlighted area for the range outside of the +100/-100 but Id like to highlight points above and below 1 standard deviation from the long term mean. In the picture below.
[ideally I want the area above and below 1 std dev to appear the same as in the addCCI chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgfIY.jpg)

```
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)

y <- rnorm(31,2,1)
x <- seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"),as.Date("2015-01-31"),1)
d<-data.frame(cbind(x,y))
d$pmean <- mean(d$y)
d$m1d <- mean(d$y)-sd(d$y)
d$p1d <- mean(d$y)+sd(d$y)

d2 <- xts(d[,-1],order.by=as.Date(d$x))
chartSeries(d2$y, TA="addCCI(5)")

ggplot(d, aes(as.Date(x))) +
    geom_line(aes(y = y, colour = "blue")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = pmean, colour = "red")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = p1d, colour = "red")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = m1d, colour = "red"))
```

This bit of code is what I used to create the examples above.
Is this even possible in ggplot2 and if so, I would appreciate any help in accomplishing it.
Thank you in advance